# Does the attempted assassination in In the Line of Fire reference the assassination of William McKinley?

Tags: in-the-line-of-fire

In *In the Line of Fire*, the attempted assassination scene bears striking resemblance to the assassination of President William McKinkey (assassin waiting to shake hands with the president, both assassins had their guns covered by cloth). I have not, but has anyone found a source commenting on this scene's resemblance to the McKinley assassination?

Comment: Not a proper source but IMDB already had a note for it: "3) Mitch Leary tries to shoot the President (Jim Curley) with a gun concealed in a handkerchief, which was how Leon Czolgosz assassinated William McKinley."

Comment: Trivia: Old Ebbitt Grill, used in location shooting for the film, was, in its former boarding house location, home for President William McKinley during his tenure in the United States House of Representatives.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby works for me ;) thx